# SwiftUI list multiple custom row edit option

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I need a multiple rows edit option for SwiftUI list

1. My login screen in NavigationView
2. After login Home screen is tab
   bar
3. one of the tab is list view (I need edit option for this
   list)

Here is my total code

first screen I have only simple navigation view with text fields and button.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = HomeViewModel()
    
    //@State var title = "Home"
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $viewModel.selectedView) {
            TasksView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(“one”)
                Text(“one”)
            }.tag(0)
            DashboardView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(“two”)
                Text(“two”)
            }.tag(1)
            NotifcationsView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(“some”)
                Text(“some”)
            }.tag(2)
            SettingsView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(“set”)
                Text("Se")
            }.tag(3)
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(viewModel.title) , displayMode: .inline)
    }
    
}


struct TasksView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = TViewModel()
    @State var segmentSelection = 0
    @State var selection = Set<String>()
//    @State var editMode = EditMode.active
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $viewModel.segmentSelection, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(0..<self.viewModel.segments.count) {index in
                    Text(self.viewModel.segments[index]).tag(index)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding(5)
            //MyTaskListView()
            List (selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(viewModel.mt){ t in
                    //TaskCell(t : task)
                    Text("Title")
                }
                .onDelete(perform: viewModel.delete)
            }
        }.onAppear{
            self.viewModel.requestMYTasks()
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        
    }
    
    init() {
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = Colors.navBarColor
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: Colors.navBarColor], for: .normal)
    }
    
    
}
```

after keeping simple row also , edit is not working

Answer (score 0):

`EditButton` tracks edit mode automatically, so just remove your explicit state and all works (on replicated code, Xcode 11.4)

```swift
//@State var editMode = EditMode.active         // remove this

List (selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(viewModel.myTasks){ task in
                    TaskCell(task : task)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: viewModel.delete)
//                .environment(\.editMode, self.$editMode)    // ... and this
            }
.navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
```

Comment: @Prathap, have you provided all code? Which Xcode/env do you use? As stated in answer it is tasted and worked.

Comment: I have only one screen with tabbar and segmented controll with that list , remaining working fine, problem with this list only , I have replaced simple Text("title") with that custom row , even I have same problem